# shortcuts for Add new solution folder to solution

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I create or customize shortcuts for Add new solution folder to solution ?

Tried find in Options > Keyboard but could not find action for this.

Comment: Which visualstudio version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to:

> Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard

then select

> Project.AddNewSolutionFolder

and assign a shortcut.

If you don't find it you can search writing in the input named: **Show commands containing**

[image]

Comment: @Thank, I am blind :D

Answer (score 0):

For me the answer from @giammin didn't work, but using `Project.NewFolder` instead of `Project.AddNewSolutionFolder` did.

This is the shortcut for right-clicking a folder in the solution explorer and then adding a new folder (similarly to pressing `Alt+Shift+C` to add a new class).

Comment: You have to use different shortcuts for adding project folders and solution folders.